# remove specific element from all arrays inside object

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I want to remove all `'main-1-3'` elements inside arrays:

```js
const a = {
  white: ['main-1-1'],
  red: ['main-1-3'],
  orange: [],
  green: [],
  blue: [],
}

const colors = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];

for(let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    a[colors[i]].splice(a[colors[i]].indexOf('main-1-3'), 1); 
}

console.log(a)
```

But as you see if there is no such element other elements are removed too! I want to only remove the `'main-1-3'` in all of the arrays?

How can I fix this?

Comment: _"How can I fix this?"_ - Just don't stuff everything into one line, and respect the return value of `.indexOf()`...

Comment: I got that I respect it from now on...

Answer (score 2):

You should first check that the item really is in the array. `indexOf` an item that isn't in the array will return `-1`, which will mess up the `splice` call:

```js
const a = {
  white: ['main-1-1'],
  red: ['main-1-3'],
  orange: [],
  green: [],
  blue: [],
}

const colors = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];

for(let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    const index = a[colors[i]].indexOf('main-1-3');
    if (index >= 0) {
        a[colors[i]].splice(index, 1); 
    }
}

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over `a`'s [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and `filter` out all the `main-1-3` elements.

```js
const a = {
  white: ['main-1-1'],
  red: ['main-1-3', 'main-1-1'],
  orange: [],
  green: [],
  blue: ['main-1-2'],
}

for (let [key, arr] of Object.entries(a)) {
  a[key] = arr.filter(el => el !== 'main-1-3');
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether string `'main-1-3'` exist in arrays in `a`.

Because if the string `main-1-3` doesnot exist in the arrays in object `a`, the index will return `-1`.

`Array.splice(-1, 1)` will delete the last node in the array, this is what happening in your case.

**Array.splice(-1, 1) Example**

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
myArray.splice(-1, 1);
console.log(myArray); // Last element removed
```

As you see in the above example, `Array.splice(-1, 1)` deletes the last node. So you have to ensure that your index `a[colors[i]].indexOf('main-1-3')` is not `-1` or else the last nodes in your array will be deleted.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const a = {
  white: ['main-1-1'],
  red: ['main-1-3'],
  orange: [],
  green: [],
  blue: [],
}

const colors = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  const index = a[colors[i]].indexOf('main-1-3');
  if (index > -1) {
    a[colors[i]].splice(index, 1);
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate through each array and filter out the item `main-1-3`:

```js
const a = {
  white: ['main-1-1'],
  red: ['main-1-3'],
  orange: [],
  green: [],
  blue: [],
}
const colors = ['white', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue'];

colors.forEach(e => a[e] = a[e].filter(n => n !== 'main-1-3'))

console.log(a)
```